# Authentication in firebase with angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

Good evening!
I use angular and firebase as authentication(email and password).
Here is my problem, the index of my website displays a form of connection, there are three kinds of users. The user 1 has access to parts that does not appear even at the user 2 who also has access to parties that the user 3. I would like to redirect the user to the page that corresponds to him. Does firebase authentication make it?

Answer (score 0):

I think in firebase after authentication you may get an UID, using this UID create the DB, i think it will be easy for your problem

Comment: Please detail your answer please, I am a beginner with the firebase database

Comment: After doing the authentication in the firebase console you can see an UID use this UID to store data in the database